# C++ type for functor structs

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14, functor

I am trying to have a single variable with some type that can be assigned to some of the C++ standard functors (eg: `std::plus`, `std::multiplies`, etc...)

Here is the definition for `std::plus` (from this [link](https://m.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/plus/)):

```cpp
template <class T> struct plus : binary_function <T,T,T> {
  T operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {return x+y;}
};
```

I tried

```cpp
#include <functional>

std::binary_function<int, int, int> func = std::plus;
```

but it doesn't work.
How do I define it properly?

Comment: You wouldn't want to anyway. The operator is non-virtual and you're slicing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single variable to hold all kinds of callables with same signature is `std::function<int(int,int)>`. Though the functors need to either have the template argument specified or deducde them from arguments:

```
std::function<int(int,int)> func2 = [](int a,int b){ return std::plus{}(a,b);};
```

or

```
std::function<int(int,int)> func = std::plus<int>{};
```

Comment: Found the latter really beginner friendly. Thanks.